# Rename environment variables

Tags: variables, heroku, rename, environment

Heroku currently provides the database credentials as one connection string i.e: `postgres://foo:bar@baz/fubarDb`.

My development environment consists of a PostgreSQL container and an app container orchestrated with a `docker-compose` file. The `docker-compose` file supplies environment variables from `.env` file which currently looks a little like this:

```
DB_USER=foo
DB_PASS=bar
DB_HOST=baz
```

These credentials are passed to my app as environment variables and all is well. The problem is that in order to make this work, I have to have a `null` check in my db connection info to see if there is a full database URL and use that...otherwise fall back to individual credentials....

Comment: Why don't you just change the environment variables your _container_ wants?

Comment: @Chris because my postgres container in my compose file(used for dev) needs the individual vars which it uses to provision itself. My app container was then also using those same vars and I could be sure they were in sync and consitent. Now, I have to support the URL for production and the individual vars for development and do a null check on the URL like this: https://github.com/robertmain/meal-plan/blob/master/src/server/app.module.ts#L26-L31 it's messy.

Comment: You shouldn't _have_ a Postgres container on Heroku. You can't run your own. The only inbound connections permitted are on ports 443 and 80 for `web` processes. Use a hosted database like [Heroku's own Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/), or similiar.

Comment: I _don't_ have a postgres container on heroku, the postgres container is my local dev environment.I believe I said that.

The dev postgres container means that my credentials have to be individual, Heroku requires that they be all in a connection string.

Comment: Then why are the environment variables that Heroku provides relevant? What's the crossover between your dev Postgres container and the environment provided by your production Heroku app?

Comment: My dev container requires them to be present in a certain format, heroku requires another. The lack of uniformity requires null checks in my app (see above) which is frustrating

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the relevant code here instead of asking us to go off-site. The Stack Overflow model is partly about helping future users as well as current ones and links can break. Also, please see [ask], which says in part "pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". The easier you make it for us to understand your question the better luck you'll have.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to leave out as much info about my actual app as possible and focus more on heroku since that was the topic of my question. But you're right - I updated the question to be more detailed.

Comment: D'oh. Figured it out. I updated my compose file to generate a connection string (like Heroku provides) and provide that to my app container. Not sure why that eluded me...

Comment: Good job chasing this down on your own! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! So, it turns out the solution, was to modify my `docker-compose` file to take the environment variables and concatenate them into a connection string thusly:

```
diff --git a/docker-compose.yml b/docker-compose.yml
index 21f0d47..74a574e 100644
--- a/docker-compose.yml
+++ b/docker-compose.yml
@@ -16,14 +16,10 @@ services:
       context: .
       target: base
     environment:
-      - APP_NAME
-      - DB_HOST
-      - DB_PORT
-      - DB_NAME
-      - DB_USER
-      - DB_PASS
-      - NODE_ENV
-      - PORT
+      APP_NAME: ${APP_NAME}
+      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
+      PORT: ${PORT}
+      DATABASE_URL: postgres://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
     user: "1000:1000"
     ports:
       - "127.0.0.1:${PORT}:${PORT}"
```

No more trying to guess which environment variables to look for!

Comment: There's obvious confusion here between:

.env file which is used for variable substitution in the docker-compose.YAML file, and should resolve when you run docker-compose config env_file element in a service definition, which is just setting the environment file to send to docker engine when starting the container, as a definition of runtime nvironment. Compose will not parse this file which is opaque to him.

Source:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6581

Comment: @AntonioErcoleDeLuca I'm not sure what you mean. If the .env file isn't parsed and substituted in the yaml file - where are those values coming from?